# How many events if the probability of an event is given

Tags: probability

Lets say there are $N$ bus-stops and there could be either 0 or 1 bus at any station at any given time. The probability of a bus being on the station is $P_{rel}$. What can one say about the total buses on $N$ stations? Lets assume there are total 1000 observations.

PS : I am not sure if the problem is well-posed.

Comment: I believe it would help to know much time each bus spends on a stop compared to how much time it spends driving between them.

Comment: Lets assume its a discrete event system. I appear magically on all bus stations every 10 minutes at the same time and note down if bus is present of absent.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I was wrong. I thought we were estimating the total number of busses on the road. Then assuming that each bus stop's variable is independant of the others', the sum over all stops will be binomial, and the expectation value is $N\cdot P_{rel}$.

Comment: The 1000 observations are irrelevant, the problem is well-posed, and I am not sure if the OP knows why the result is what is stated in a post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the expected number of buses at bus stops is $N\cdot P_{rel}$.

Comment: I also thought so. But the solution seems to be on the line of binomial probability formula. This is an old 'math club' problem and either the problem or solution may not be correct but I am not sure

Comment: That is binomial. See comment on the original question.

Comment: Binomial assumes independence but independence is neither given as a hypothesis nor necessary to reach the result. By the way, @Dilawar, do you know how to prove the assertion in the answer?

Comment: Yes, I agree, independence was an assumption.

Comment: @Did Yes, I worked it out. This was very helpful http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bradluen/stat2/lecture19.pdf

Comment: @stevemarvell Independence was not an assumption of the question.

Comment: @Dilawar Why do you refer me to notes about binomial distributions when I pointed out that these are not part of the picture?

Comment: @Did Well, I was getting confused why the answer is not like ${n \choose k} (p)^k (1-p){n-k}$. Then I realized that I was confusing finding probability of getting k events (lecture note) and expected number of event. But if you think that I am missing something, please feel free to post a detailed solution. I am going through elementary statistics.

Comment: @Dilawar Precisely, finding the probabilities would be a mess without independence but finding the expected number of events is quite different, expectation being **linear**. If each event from a collection of $N$ has probability $p$, then the expected number of events happening is $Np$, irrespectively of their stochastic relations.